# an array list with n rows and four columns in c#

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

I need a clear example that shows me how to define a list that has n rows and 4 columns and how to use it. I need a list to save my data like the below image. as you see this could be a dictionary.

[image: list to have 4 rows and 4 columns]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a class with all the above properties

```
public class Sample
{
  public string vocabulary { get; set; }
  public string meaning { get; set; }
  public int number { get; set; }
  public int  group { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can create a **`List`** of type **`Sample`**,

```
List<Sample> yourList = new List<Sample>();
```

You can add items to the list as below

```
  yourList.Add(new Sample { vocabulary = "massive", meaning = "very big", number = 5, group = 15 });
```

You can access them later like this, if you want the first element,

```
 var result = yourList[0];
```

Comment: yes... as Sajeetharan mentioned, with a custom class you can create any dimension List.

Comment: I'm not a c# developer. Can you show me the complete example. How to add items and how to access them?

Comment: @UserMat check above

Answer (score 1):

this is the easiest and best way of doing it.  You need to create a new class and then create new instances of the class and then add it to the list and then use LINQ to get the data out

```
void Main()
{
 var list = new List<myClass>()
 list.Add(new myClass() {
 Vocabluary = "Vocabluary ", 
 Meaning = "meaning", 
 Number = 1, 
 Group = 2})
}

public class myClass
{

 public string Vocabluary { get; set; }
 public string Meaning { get; set; }
 public int Number { get; set; }
 public int Group { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes... as Sajeetharan mentioned, with a custom class you can create an any dimensions List. but i don't think you need to think about dimension in C#... it is a bit more high level than that.

just simply create a class and put everything you need in it...

```
public class CustomClass{
    public string d1;
    public int d2;
    public string d3;
    public string d4;
    ...
    //you can easily create a N dimension class
}
```

to access it and apply it

```
public void Main(){
    List<CustomClass> list = new List<CustomClass>();
    CustomClass cc = new CustomClass();
    cc.d1 = "v1";
    cc.d2 = 0; //v2
    list.Add(cc);

    //to access it
    foreach(CustomClass tmpClass in list)
    {
        string d1Value = tmpClass.d1;
        int d2Value = tmpClass.d2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: This poorly formatted code is almost identical @Sajeetharan's code

Comment: yes, they are the same thus they should be identical. i just emphasize c# usually do not talk too much about dimension. and it would be helpful if you can talk more about poor formatted code instead of  judging others without anything actually inputted. thanks

Comment: If you are just adding information to another answer, you should comment on it instead of writing an identical answer with a comment about the original.

Comment: it is the answer of the question in the comment and certainly i dont think it is identical to talk about c# container's dimension and class relationship. nvm, its ok. just clarifying the meaning of the poor formatted code and it looks irrelevant to its literal meaning.

Comment: No indentations or spacing. In `CustomClass` either you are using fields with a implicit `public` access modifier, which would break encapsulation, or you they are `private`. If they are `private` then your second code block would not compile.

Comment: i just wrote those code without compiler, but i agreed there was mistake on the class. and good to know the meaning of the poor formatted code.  Thanks for your time :)